# Select yaml element in vim

Tags: vim, yaml

In this `yaml` file:

```
 level1:
   level2:
     element1: 'a'
     element2: 'b'
```

The cursor is on the 2nd line (`level2`). I would want to visually select the whole `level2` at once, not by entering visual mode and manually scrolling through the lines.

With xml I'd do `vat` to select the whole tag. Is there a similar way to do this with `yaml`?

Comment: XML has clearly identifiable opening and closing tags so things like `it` or `at` are relatively straightforward to implement but indent-based syntax is harder to deal with. You could try [this plugin](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object).

Comment: Also: https://vimways.org/2018/transactions-pending/#text-objects-in-indentation-and-around-indentation

Comment: as long as there is an empty line after the level, you could use `V}`